# Jquery collapsible TR to be hidden

Tags: html, jquery, arrays

I am using collapsible rows from the below mentioned link 
But i am not able to figure out what should be done to keep the chil rows hidden util someone clicks the parent tr.

I tried something like

https://jsfiddle.net/p9mtqhm7/52/.

```
<script>
 \$(document).ready(function(){
\$('.childtr').hide();
});
\$('.freasontr').click(function(){
//alert('hi');
    if(\$(this).hasClass(\"collapsed\")){
        \$(this).nextUntil('tr.freasontr')
        .find('td')
        .parent()
        .find('td > div')
        .slideDown(\"fast\", function(){
            var set = \$(this);
            set.replaceWith(set.contents());
        });
        \$(this).removeClass(\"collapsed\");
// \$(this).addClass(\"collapsed\");
//alert('hello');
    } else {
        \$(this).nextUntil('tr.freasontr')
        .find('td')
        .wrapInner('<div style=\"display: block;\" />')
        .parent()
        .find('td > div')
        .slideUp(\"fast\");
        \$(this).addClass(\"collapsed\");
    }
// \$(this).removeClass(\"collapsed\");
//alert('bye');
});
</script> ";
```

What can be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.freasontr').each(function(){
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Or

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.freasontr').each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.freasontr')
        .find('td')
        .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
        .parent()
        .find('td > div')
        .slideUp("fast");
        $(this).addClass("collapsed");
    });
});
```